# Ignoring log patterns of dependencies

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, slf4j, log4j2

I have a Spring Boot project with a dependency to a third party library. This library uses SLF4J with Log4j2 for logging, and has a log4j2.xml with a pattern layout defined.

The problem is that the pattern layout of this dependency is used as the pattern for my application, ignoring the layout defined in application.properties.

If I can't modify the source code of this third party lib, is possible to configure my app in order to ignore the log4j2.xml?

Comment: Are you using Maven as your build tool. In that case, you can exclude the third party library from pulling in logger implementations. Can you check if the below solution works for you.                                           <dependency>
    <groupid>com.abc</groupid>
    <artifactid>thirdPartyArtifact</artifactid>
    <version>1</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupid>org.slf4j</groupid>
        <artifactid>slf4j-log4j12</artifactid>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution that you can try is to define your own `log4j2` configuration file and give its path in `log4j.configurationFile` system property. When you define your own `log4j2` configuration file, you can control how much logging you want and in which pattern.

The reason behind this is - When `Log4j` starts it tries to locate all the `ConfigurationFactory` plugins and arrange them in weighted order from **highest to lowest**. And as per [log4j2 Automation Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Automatic_Configuration), setting system property `log4j.configurationFile` has highest weight.

If `log4j` will found configuration file using this system property, then it will not scan classpath for locating `log4j2.xml` file which is present in your dependent library.